# Seaborn twin plot not working as expected

Tags: plot, seaborn, bar-chart, linechart

I want to make a twin plot using seaborn but for in some case the barplot ends up on the left part of the plot, while it's fine for most other variables. What should be fixed?
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nN1B.png)

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))

ax1 = sns.barplot(x=cat, y="Number of opportunities", data=df)
ax1.set_ylabel("Number of opportunities", fontsize=16)
plt.xticks(
    rotation=45, 
    horizontalalignment='right',
    fontweight='light',
    fontsize='x-large'  
)

color = 'c'

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2 = sns.lineplot(x=cat, y="Win Ratio", data=df, linewidth=2, color=color)
```

Comment: Seaborn uses a categorical x-axis for bar plots. And a numeric x-axis for a line plot (when the data is numeric). To get both work together, you could convert the 'cat' column of the dataframe to string. `df['cat'] = df['cat'].astype(str)`.

Answer (score 0):

As Explained by Johan, 'cat' column should be converted to string:

```
df['cat'] = df['cat'].astype(str). – JohanC
```